# How can i add a navigation drawer to an existing application?

Tags: android, design-patterns, navigation

I'm new to making apps and I'm working on this college project which I need help with, I want to create a navigation drawer for my application but I don't know how to, I have already created login, register, edit profile and main page to my app but now I want to add a navigation drawer to it without making a whole new project, for example I want the main page to have that drawer and it will contain 'edit profile" etc. so I can go to different activities from it, I've seen a lot of videos but don't really understand yet since they all make new projects, how can I link all of my activities to it without needing to create a new project?
main_activity code

```
package net.authenticatorapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT_CODE = 1023 ;
    TextView fullName,email,phone,verifyMsg;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String userId;
    Button resendCode;
    Button resetPassLocal,changeProfileImage;
    FirebaseUser user;
    ImageView profileImage;
    StorageReference storageReference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nav_activity_main);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.profilePhone);
        fullName = findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        email    = findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        resetPassLocal = findViewById(R.id.resetPasswordLocal);

        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        changeProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.changeProfile);


        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        StorageReference profileRef = storageReference.child("users/"+fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()+"/profile.jpg");
        profileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                Picasso.get().load(uri).into(profileImage);
            }
        });

        resendCode = findViewById(R.id.resendCode);
        verifyMsg = findViewById(R.id.verifyMsg);


        userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
         user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(!user.isEmailVerified()){
            verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resendCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            resendCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {

                    user.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Verification Email Has been Sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d("tag", "onFailure: Email not sent " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }




        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                    phone.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("phone"));
                    fullName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("fName"));
                    email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));

                }else {
                    Log.d("tag", "onEvent: Document do not exists");
                }
            }
        });


        resetPassLocal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final EditText resetPassword = new EditText(v.getContext());

                final AlertDialog.Builder passwordResetDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                passwordResetDialog.setTitle("Reset Password ?");
                passwordResetDialog.setMessage("Enter New Password > 8 Characters long.");
                passwordResetDialog.setView(resetPassword);

                passwordResetDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // extract the email and send reset link
                        String newPassword = resetPassword.getText().toString();
                        user.updatePassword(newPassword).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Reset Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password Reset Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                passwordResetDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       // close
                    }
                });

                passwordResetDialog.create().show();

            }
        });

        changeProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // open gallery
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),EditProfile.class);
                i.putExtra("fullName",fullName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("email",email.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("phone",phone.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
//

            }
        });


    }




    public void logout(View view) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();//logout
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
        finish();
    }


}
```

main_activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:onClick="logout"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resetPasswordLocal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13999999"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Your Name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Your Email Address"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profilePhone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Phone Number"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/verifyMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Email Not Verfied !"
        android:textColor="#C2185B"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resendCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Verify Now"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/verifyMsg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetPasswordLocal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Reset Password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/changeProfile"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Full Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileImage"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileName"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileEmail"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_local_phone_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Phone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeProfile"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Change Profile"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePhone"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.59000003" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Profile"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.107"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Navigation UI can make your life easy.

Comment: @Eyosiyas i'm not sure how to do so, Should I make a whole new project?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui

Comment: @HanaaAlaouiBelghiti you don't have to create a new project.

Comment: @Eyosiyas then how can i do it? I've watched a lot of videos and I literally have no clue

Comment: Provide your MainActivity layout and code file.

Comment: @Eyosiyas I have added them in the question now

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a couple of changes.
The changes are as follows.
First, we need to modify the **main_activity.xml** layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:onClick="logout"
        android:text="Logout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resetPasswordLocal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13999999"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Your Name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Your Email Address"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profilePhone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Phone Number"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/verifyMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Email Not Verfied !"
        android:textColor="#C2185B"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resendCode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Verify Now"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/verifyMsg" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetPasswordLocal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Reset Password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/changeProfile"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Full Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileImage"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileName"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileEmail"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_local_phone_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Phone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeProfile"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Change Profile"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePhone"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.59000003" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Profile"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.107"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Next, we will create **nav_header.xml** layout file in **layout** resource directory for the Navigation Drawer Header layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Nav Drawer Text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and We need also to create a menu under **menu** resource directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_call"
        android:title="Call" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_message"
        android:title="Message" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_history"
        android:title="History" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:title="View contact" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_edit"
        android:title="Edit contact" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:title="Log out" />
</menu>
```

Go to **MainActivity.java** and add the following.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nav_activity_main);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.profilePhone);
        fullName = findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        email    = findViewById(R.id.profileEmail);
        resetPassLocal = findViewById(R.id.resetPasswordLocal);

        //You need a toolbar here. Create your own or use the Theme's one.
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

       ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
       drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
       toggle.syncState();
       navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_call)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Do this for the rest of the navigation menu items.
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Go to your **strings.xml** resource file and add the following

```
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Drawer Open</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Drawer Closed</string>
```

I think we are done.